# How to diagnose constant high cpu usage from cron

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

Just noticed this, cron is constantly maxing out my cpu on Ubuntu under the user sabnzbd. Sabnzbd isn't doing anything active. Stopping Sabnzbd doesn't kill that process.

How do I get to the bottom of what's causing this?

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                        
 1736 sabnzbd   20   0   76344   8408    752 S 399.7   0.1  20:46.45 cron
```

Comment: Did you try killing the process (`kill 1736`)?

Comment: Yes, killing the process removes it until reboot. About a minute after reboot it's back to 400%

Comment: Show us the result of `crontab -e`

Comment: This is the crontab for user sabnzbd

https://pastebin.com/pt3Njfbq